# MySQL - Are there performance penalties with using UTF8 encoding in the connection string?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, unicode, utf-8, ado.net

Is there any performance issue associated with using UTF8 in the connection string when connecting to a MySQL database? (ex: using "charset=utf8" in ADO.NET or "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8" in JDBC)

Assuming that the same setting can be used for different databases, will the be any conversion issues if the server database isn't configured to support UTF8?

For example, I know that for SQL Server there are some hefty performance issues with table scans when parameters are sent as Unicode against a non-Unicode column (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/18/troubleshooting-sql-index-performance-on-varchar-columns/), and was wondering if there is something similar for MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

Long, rambling, answer on the topic and related items:

All utf8mb4 all the time is the "best" approach.

As for performance penalty when asking MySQL to do a charset conversion during `INSERT` or `SELECT`, it is minor compared to all the other issues - indexing, searching, network bandwidth, parsing statement, etc.  A very bad performance bump is doing a table scan due to the lack of a decent index.  For larger tables, disk I/O can be an overwhelming factor.  But functions, expressions, character set issues, etc are minor.

On the other hand, if you are `JOINing` two tables and the datatypes of the joining column(s) do not match sufficiently, this can cause a table scan instead of an index usage.  Mismatched `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION` can *sometimes* lead to this performance hit.

Back to your question...  First, you establish what encoding is used for the characters in the client.  Your example showed utf8.  (The spelling perhaps should have been UTF-8.)  Then you specify, at the column level, what character set to use for storage.  (The database has a default, which feeds to the table, which can have a default; then the column takes on the default unless it overrides.)

If the client characters are encoded one way and the column is encoded another way, there will be a conversion.  Don't worry about performance.

Note:  I did not mention "collation". That term refers to comparisons between text in the same character set.  `INSERT` and `SELECT` (aside from `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`) do not involve comparisons.

Outside MySQL, it is usually spelled "UTF-8".  Inside MySQL, that is "utf8mb4", which allows encodings as long as 4 bytes.  Inside MySQL, "utf8" refers to the 3-byte (or shorter) subset.

Note:  I did not mention "Unicode".  Use "UTF-8", not "UCS2".  (I think it is unfortunate and confusing that the JDBC connection parameters mention both 'UTF-8' and 'Unicode'.)

Comment: *"On the other hand, if you are JOINing two tables and the datatypes of the joining column(s) do not match sufficiently, this can cause a table scan instead of an index usage."* - Can't that also be the case with a non-Unicode column and a Unicode search term in a WHERE clause? If so, then that could conceivably result in *"A very bad performance bump [in] doing a table scan due to the lack of a decent [Unicode] index."*.

Comment: The issue @GordThompson raises is the same that happens in SQL Server with varchar columns and nvarchar parameters - the index is irrelevant since a full table scan is necessary

Comment: @GordThompson - in `WHERE utf8_col = 'some string'` -- the literal will converted to the column's charset and collation, so no problem.  `WHERE utf8_col = 'some string'  COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci` could lead to a table scan.

Comment: ( cc: @agentshowers ) - Thanks, Rick. I just finished a few tests on a table with an indexed `latin1` column and simply throwing `utf8` search terms at it did *not* trigger a table scan, so it appears that MySQL is more accommodating than SQL Server when it comes to that. I didn't try messing with `COLLATE` clauses, so I'll take your word on that. too. My main interest was whether a `utf8` search term like "fermé" (with "é" encoded as 0xC3A9) against an indexed `latin1` column containing "fermé" (with "é" encoded as 0xE9) would actually work (it does) and cause a table scan (it doesn't).

Comment: If you _connect_ with utf8 and send utf8 `C3A9` and insert into a `CHARACTER SET latin1` column, MySQL will convert to `E9`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that answers my question. Just for curiosity, [here's a nice study regarding implicit conversions that cause table scans and collations in SQL Server](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/)

Comment: @agentshowers - yes, an interesting link, _but_ it applies to SQL Server, not MySQL.